# Printing of non-pdf document

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printing

Can we print non-pdf document without using webview ? When I passing my url to `[UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL: url]`to this function it returns NO every time. I checked my url is absolutely valid and perfect.

One more thing my document resides in document directory.

Comment: did u checked QLPreviewController and UIDocumentInteractionController...there might be spell error...coz I don't remember the exact names...

Comment: yeah I know about all this two controller. but why this canPrintURL method return no? anybody have idea